# Use free themes and plugins from the website "wplocker"

Tags: wordpress, themes

Are there any disadvantages of using the plugins and themes from this site knowing that they are paid at other platforms...?
http://www.wplocker.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "WPlocker" seems to be a directory of themes and plugins from various sources. There is no benefit or disadvantage of using the site if it's going to take you to the vendors product page. Most of them are from Themeforest/Codecanyon which is a trusted marketplace.